# How to UV map and what s the point of it?

Tags: uv, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

[image]

hi, as you can see i ve made a shipping container model with many polygons, i d like now to apply textures on it, i d like to use Substance Painter to do that, I saw on youtube that you need to export the fbx file from blender and open it on substance painter.
do i need to create a UV map to apply textures anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are going to add textures to a mesh of any kind no matter what the program is you'll be adding the textures with you still need to have a UV map to do it, the textures get applied to an object to the mesh itself,